# GET json nested object attribute. [FromQuery]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to query for the "UserType" object, and get the attribute "name"
So the whole JSON object is User: and the api call should look like this:
`api/user?userTypeName=randomUserTypeName`

Where I can search for a specific userTypeName, and return the name.

API call:

Here I want to user the FromQuery, to be able to search for the userTypeName and check for the userTypeName to be equal to the entered Name.

```
// GET: /api/User/userTypeName
[HttpGet("{userTypeName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAsync(([FromQuery(Name = "userTypeName")]string userTypeName) {
    var result = await ctx.User
        .Include(x => x.UserType)
        .Where(x => x.UserType.Name.ToLower() == UserTypeName.ToLower())
        .ToListAsync();

    if (result == null) return BadRequest();

    return result;
}
```

The object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "userTypeId": 1,
    "userType": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "randomUserTypeName",
    "users": 
    [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "userTypeId": 1,
            "userUrl": "https://userurl",
            "username": "eee",
            "password": "eee",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `userTypeName` from Route by request like `/api/User/userTypeName`, your action should like

```
[HttpGet("{userTypeName}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAsync(string userTypeName) {
    var result = await ctx.User
        .Include(x => x.UserType)
        .Where(x => x.UserType.Name.ToLower() == UserTypeName.ToLower())
        .ToListAsync();

    if (result == null) return BadRequest();

    return result;
}
```

If you want to access `userTypeName` from Query by request like `api/user?userTypeName=randomUserTypeName`, your action should like

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetAsync([FromQuery(Name = "userTypeName")]string userTypeName) {
    var result = await ctx.User
        .Include(x => x.UserType)
        .Where(x => x.UserType.Name.ToLower() == UserTypeName.ToLower())
        .ToListAsync();

    if (result == null) return BadRequest();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It won't let me use [HttpGet] without defining the ("{userTypeName}") attribute.

I already have a GetAsync method, for only getting the Users. Does this conflict somehow?

Comment: @Langehk What is the reason you used `{userTypeName}` and `FromQuery`?

Comment: I'm just trying to query for the userTypeName. And if I don't use {userTypeName} it gives me an error.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

`
Proj.Presentation.MVC.API.UserController.GetAsync (Proj.Presentation.MVC)
Proj.Presentation.MVC.API.UserController.GetAsync (proj.Presentation.MVC)
/_Host `

Comment: @Langehk This is caused by you are using the `HttpGet` for multiple action. Change `[HttpGet("{userTypeName}")]` to `[HttpGet("[action]")]`.